# Use of ESD Tape on device

Tags: esd

Where to use ESD tape?
I have ATmega 16 IC . So if i want to put ESD tape, where to use it?

My Atmega IC freezes.So I think it is due to use ESD effect.So I want to ESD tape on it.
Shall I put it on the device without touching the GPIO pins?

Comment: This question makes no sense. If the chip is in use __and__ it's because of static discharges (unlikely as it may be), it's because: 1. You are mis-handling it in a very big way. 2. The device/board it is in/on is no good.

Comment: What makes you think it's a ESD problem? Is your board connected to anything else?

Comment: @Asmyldof I am connecting the GPIO to FOD and Triac for controlling AC Appliances.

Comment: @DmitryGrigoryev I am connecting the GPIO to FOD and Triac for controlling AC Appliances.
So sometimes my Chip freezes.It stuck.So I think there might be problem due to Static Charge.

Comment: @chandan What is FOD? Foreign Objects and Debris? Anyway, AC can upset low-voltage electronics in many ways, without having to do with ESD. I suggest you ask another question, showing your schematics, it may be an interesting question on its own.

Comment: @DmitryGrigoryev thank you .
I have put the schematic.
http://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/242259/arduino-freezing-issue

Comment: Usually the first culprit for MCU freezing, especially when programmed by newbies, is some error in the firmware. Not necessarily a "bug", but code that fails to interact with the external hardware correctly, for example when reading the state of a push button without proper SW debouncing and then taking wrong decisions. Check carefully your firmware.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

ESD tape is used to protect sensitive devices **during storage and handling**, not in normal operation. It is applied on conductive parts like pins and PCB traces.

Since ESD tape is conductive, it will contribute to capacitive coupling of conductors it is applied on. Some kinds of ESD tape dissipate electrical charges by attracting moisture from the air, which you also don't want on a working device.